# how to insert values from checkbox to MYSQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
<table width="200" border="0">          
<tr>
  <td><p>
    <?php while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="module" value="<?php echo $row1['MID']?>" id="<?php echo $row1['MID']?>">
    <?php echo $row1['ModuleName']?></label>
    <br>
    <?php }?>
  </p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I use this code  to outout the checkboxes,and the  checkboxes appear allright.

I m not sure about how,the data can be  saved to the MYSL table.
the table i drew is in the form:
student_module{studentID,ModuleID}

what is the code i should write to enter the data to that table.
One student can enroll to many modules.

Comment: why not follow what already has been answered for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243879/how-do-i-insert-the-value-from-a-checkbox-into-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="" ><?php echo $row1['ModuleName']?>
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
$selected_checkbox = "";
foreach ($checkbox1 as $checkbox1) 
{
$selected_checkbox .= $checkbox1 . ", ";
}
$selected_checkbox = substr($selected_checkbox, 0, -2);
 // now here in your insert query take mid='".$selected_checkbox."';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Using ajax functionality:**

By clicking on checkbox collect the value of `studentID` and `ModuleID` and pass to the ajax method and then in your server end page, you can update db record.

### Without ajax functionality

Post the form when user clicking on checkbox or put a save button below to submit the form on a PHP page and then you can collect all your values and update db accordingly.